# There's a value limit for iOS Accessibility?

Tags: ios, objective-c, accessibility

When I set an accessibilityLabel with values greater than 99999 (ex: 100000), the iOS VoiceOver doesn't read it on a proper way. Somebody knows why? I am looking for some reason for that on apple docs but didn't find nothing.

Comment: what does it read for valu greater than 99999?

Comment: "one zero zero zero zero zero " Instead "one hundred thousand"

Comment: well thats just a string hence it reads every character. If you want to voice over to think it as a number you should use number formatter.

Comment: Yeah, I tried formatter but I got no success. :(

Comment: @DanielBrevesFerreira Can you post your code?

Comment: My guess is that once you hit a certain number of digits, VoiceOver (and/or its Text-to-Speech module) figures that the number could be a phone number or some other form of digit sequence that's not a number, so call it out digit by digit instead. At least on US English VoiceOver, "100,000" is read out as "one hundred thousand", while ["8675309"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6WTdTwcmxyo) (with or without a hyphen!) is read out digit by digit.

Comment: By the way, you can also repro these cases w/o writing code by opening the iOS Notes app and typing in various numbers, then getting VoiceOver to read them out. Some other fun cases - "3m" is read out as "3 meters", and ":)" as "smiley".

Comment: Maybe the solution will be write my own "voice parser" :(